# Struggling in a calculus : what is the time complexity of these two python algorithms?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, string, time-complexity

I am really struggling to compute time complexity of two solutions I came up with in a coding exercise. Could you help me, with a bit of explanations ?

The problem is the following :

Write a function to find the longest common prefix string amongst an array of strings.

If there is no common prefix, return an empty string "".

**Example:** strs = ["flower","flow","flight"], Output = "fl"

My first solution is based on the use of a dict. The first idea is to compare each letter of the first word with others in the array, and store in a dict the index of the more far you can go with respect to the first word.
Then, we return the first word until the minimum in the values of the dict.

```
def longestCommonPrefix(strs):
    
    strg = strs[0]
    d = {}
    
    for word in strs:
        
        d[word] = 0
        
        for i, letter in enumerate(strg):
            try:
                if word[i] == letter:
                    d[word]+=1
                else:
                    break
            except:
                break
    
    return strg[:min(d.values())]
```

In that solution, we go through the array once, but go through the first word every time.

The second idea is to first sort the array, and compare each letter of the shortest string with all the other words :

```
def longestCommonPrefix(self, strs: List[str]) -> str:
      
        s = ""
        strs.sort(key = len)
        for i in range(len(strs[0])):             
            if all(strs[0][i] == word[i] for word in strs):
                s += strs[0][i]
            else:
                break
        return s
```

Here, we go through the whole array for each letter of the shortest string, and we sorted the array at first.

What are the complexities of these two solutions ?

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: The first one seems to be `O(n*m)` as it runs for every word and every letter (though possibly stopping before completing a word). The second one has a sort (`O(n*logn)`) and then two for's (`O(n^2)`), thus `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Mmmmh could you a bite less elusive please ? :) I didn't understand completely.

In the first algorithm, we have O(n\*m), where n is the length of the array, and m the length of the first string, right ? 

And for the second, we loop, after the sorting, through the first string (let's say its length is M), and then each time through the whole array, let's say of length N. So the complexity is O(N*M) no ? Why should it be O(n^2) ? Why two for's ?

Thus, the second is faster because the length of the min is always less than the length of the first string ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: I believe you are right! The only thing I think you missed is that `sort` also has a time complexity (`O(nlogn)`). Sorry for mixing `n` and `m` there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set`s. This type of object has a built-in function called `set.intersection`. The code would seem like

```py
def intersectionwithset(strings:list):
    list_of_sets = [set(i[:]) for i in strings]
    intersection = list(set.intersection(*list_of_sets))
    # in this case it will return a list with the letters present in all strings

    return intersection
```

I also compute the time of all three solution (with the list you propose). Here's the results:

1. 772 µs for the first solution
2. 678 µs for the second solution
3. 225 µs for the solution I propose

Hope I ansewered your question

Comment: This is not what the op referred to when they said "time complexity". See [Time Complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity).

Comment: Hello ! Thank you for your idea and your help.

Anyway, I was more into computing the theoretical time complexity, using the big O notation for example !

Comment: Oh, and your solution, even if it is a lot faster, doesn't seem to work : set used in string doesn't keep the right order, thus the intersection returned is right